# Не присваивается функция указателью на функцию

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здраствуйте!!! Не присваивается указатель на функцию, выдаёт ошибку:
E0144 значение типа "void (Menu::*)()" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "void (*)()"
Подскажите, что делать?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

class Menu {
public:
    void (*funcRun)() = run; //ошибка
    void run() {
        printf("aaaa");
    }
};
```

Comment: Потому-что у методов в C++ есть один аргумент, `this`, а у вас указатель на функцию которая принимает 0 аргументов, отсюда и ошибка, поэтому решением будет `void (*funcRun)(Menu *) = run;`

Comment: `void (Menu::*funcRun)() = &Menu::run;`

Comment: спасибо за помощь!!!